# how do I get the new value of a cell in a jquery datatables onchange event callback

Tags: jquery, datatables, onchange

I have onchange even handler and it is able to get the old value of the inpute, but what I want is the new value.

I can using jquery datatables and so far my code looks like this and I can get the old value from the datatables api interface. but I really want is the jquery object.
Thought the 'this' object I get from the onchange even would be the changed object, but it is not working like a non-datatables plain old jquery "this" object that you get passed to the onchange event,

```
var table = $('#data-table');

$('#data-table').on('change.dt', 'td', function(e) {
    var obj = table.cell($(this)); //this is the dt API and it works, I can the dt cell
    console.log(obj.data()); //this works, but it is of no use, as it is the old value
                             // the value has "changed" so I want the new value so
    console.log($(this).data("id"));  // this is always undef, even though my input has this attribute
  });
```

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/reference/event/ Cannot find that `"change.dt"`... is that documented somewhere?

Comment: Just to elaborate. I have an input text box and the "this" object passed to the onchange event callback has the updated value.   $('.hello').change(function(e) {
    alert($(this).val());
  });

Comment: Target the `<input>` not a cell `<td>`